# Get rid of google sheet autocomplete suggestions running everywhere without permission

Tags: google-sheets, autocomplete, autofill

I don't know why but google is taking hand on my typing, like an autocomplete or suggestions, in cells, in sub-menus parameters. I can't type properly anymore, it blocks my imputs, and I have to press escape on each cell I'm filling. How to get that off ?!?
Autocomplete document properties is off and i'm running windows 7 Pro. Thank you

[image: screenshots]

[image]

Comment: When you say "Autocomplete document properties is off..." what do you mean? What do you believe you did to turn that off?

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the head menu 'Tools', the option 'semi-autocomplete' is not activated anymore (unticked)

Comment: I have added a screenshot

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshot. I just wanted to be sure I and others here fully understood what you had tried. I don't have a definitive answer for you. If it is only happening with dialog boxes, it's possible that your browser is set to autocomplete forms. However, turning that off will also turn off other browser features that use autocomplete—features most people prefer to keep running.

Comment: Strangely and hopefully, today it doesn't do it anymore. I will look for the procedure you mentionned in case it happens again. Thank you very much